# Google Adsense modificados con un mismo ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

¿Es posible utilizar un mismo bloque de anuncio, es decir, el mismo código generado por la aplicación de google-adsense con un único `ID`, sobre distintas páginas?

La idea es modificar después, el tamaño del bloque de anuncio en un archivo común `CSS`, donde aplicando las directivas de `responsive-design` pueda ser utilizado para que sea mostrado correctamente en distintos dispositivos.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow! Deberías de revisar la ayuda de Google Adsense para saber cómo usar los bloques de anuncios. Si te refieres al ID que te otorgan para cada bloque de anuncios ya lleva unas características que se mantendrán. Te ruego por otra parte que revises las [preguntas apropiadas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para este foro ya que parece más un problema administrativo que de programación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí. Puedes hacer referencia al mismo `ID` desde diferentes archivos `CSS`. Unos complementarán a otros o incluso sobrescribirán los unos a los otros en caso de estar repetidos (dependiendo del orden en el que los importes en el HTML, los que estén más abajo sobrescribirán a los primeros).

Si quieres poner más de un `div` con los mismo estilos (anuncios) tendrías que poner una `clase` (las cuales se representan con un `.` primero en la hoja de estilos CSS).

Comment: @Hell0 Releyendo la pregunta me he dado cuenta de que igual no es lo que preguntas. Si no es así, dímelo y borraré la respuesta o intentaré ayudarte dependiendo de las necesidades.

Comment: No es la respuesta que esperaba. Me refiero a que pretendo borrar 'Todos' los anuncios que he creado en Adsense, y dejar uno nada mas. Entonces utilizaré un CSS de uso 'común' para aplicar las dimensiones del anunció en función del dispositivoque vaya a cargar la página, esto es `responsive-design`. Gracias igualmente por responder.

Comment: @Hell0 Sí, eso lo había entendido. Sin embargo, no sé realmente que duda tienes con eso. Se perfectamente lo que es responsive (lo he sufrido mucho jajaja) pero no entiendo tu duda. Lo que yo entiendo de tu pregunta y comentario es que quieres hacer un fichero común con ID y clases para formatear todos tus anuncios y que se vea responsive para distintas pantallas.

Comment: Correcto, es eso precisamente. La duda es que hasta ahora he estado generando códigos, con distintas dimensiones. El problema es que a medida que he ido aprendiendo, tmabién he descubierto que puedo modificar el tamaño y la forma en que se ve el anuncio, aplicando estas 'directivas' de las que hablamos(`responsive`). Por lo que se me ha ocurrido ir actualizando 'toodas' las páginas y quedarme con solo un bloque de anuncio. En el `html` únicamente aparecerá el `<script>` de `adsense`. Con esto pretendo facilitar la forma en que haré el seguimiento del anuncio.

Comment: La verdad que nunca he utilizado adsense pero supongo que le podrás poner un ID a tu script y asignarle unos estilos concretos. Luego para cada tipo de pantalla puedes usar media-queries para ir modificándolo de manera responsive a medida que reduces tu pantalla.

Comment: Acepto entonces la respuesta!